# Android: Only first permission is requested when requesting for multiple permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I need 5 permissions for my application. This is the code that I have added to the onCreate() of 1 of my activities:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 3);
            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 4);
                    }

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 5);
            }
    }
```

When the app runs it just asks for the first permission and not the remaining.
I also provided all permissions as an array to the request permission function but there also I see only the first permission popup.

Can someone please help. I am running my App on an Android M device, My target and compile sdk version is 26.

Comment: Call `requestPermissions()` once with a single `String[]` of all the permissions that you need. Customize the `String[]` to have just the permissions that you need, not ones that the user has already granted. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial).

Comment: Already tried that, same issue was seen, I have mentioned that in the question

Comment: Then perhaps you did it wrong, or perhaps you already hold the other permissions (and therefore they are not needed). Again, see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial), or [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Media/AudioRecording), in which I request multiple permissions without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};

    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

or use [Ted permisson](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission) library